# Can I convert my existing objective-C Today View widget into an iOS 14 Home Screen Widget?

Tags: ios, widget, ios14, home-screen-widget

My app already has a Today View widget, written in Objective-C. I am updating my app for iOS 14 and I wanted to include the widget as a home screen widget however the only documentation regarding iOS 14 home screen widgets utilizes Swift.

Is there any way to write an iOS 14 Home Screen Widget in Objective-C? Is there any way to easily port my existing widget over to iOS 14, or does it need to be written from scratch in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to redo it with SwiftUI.
There is no other option.